# Debezium: RestClientException: Leader not known; error code: 50004

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

I am getting exceptions when i try to deploy debezium connector to kafka-connect. As a result, snapshots are not created and also cdc streaming is blocked. The problem is I am not able to find where the issue is i.e. is it in kafka-connect, schema-registry or debezium connector

```
    {
  "name": "my-connector",  
  "config": {  
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "database.hostname": "root",  
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "USER",
    "database.password": "PASSWORD",
    "database.server.id": "184056",  
    "database.server.name": "dbz",
    "table.include.list": "T1,T2",
    "snapshot.mode": "initial",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "xxx:9092",  
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbz.myhistory",  
    "plugin.path": "/usr/share/java/debezium-mysql-connect/",
    "database.serverTimezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "snapshot.locking.mode": "none",
    "include.query": "true",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "XXX",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "XXX"
  }
}
```

kafka-connect exception logs:

```
    org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:294)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:247)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to serialize Avro data from topic dbz :
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:91)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$1(WorkerSourceTask.java:294)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: {"type":"record","name":"SchemaChangeKey","namespace":"io.debezium.connector.mysql","fields":[{"name":"databaseName","type":"string"}],"connect.name":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.SchemaChangeKey"}
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Leader not known.; error code: 50004
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:292)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:351)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:494)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:485)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:458)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:206)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:268)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:244)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:74)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Serializer.serialize(AvroConverter.java:143)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$1(WorkerSourceTask.java:294)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:294)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:247)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2021-09-20 05:29:23,849] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=my-connector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:187)
[2021-09-20 05:29:23,849] INFO Stopping down connector (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:241)
[2021-09-20 05:29:23,853] WARN Snapshot was interrupted before completion (io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource:74)
[2021-09-20 05:29:23,853] INFO Snapshot - Final stage (io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource:82)
[2021-09-20 05:29:23,854] WARN Change event source executor was interrupted (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator:132)
java.lang.InterruptedException: Interrupted while processing event SchemaChangeEvent [database=mydb, schema=null, ddl=DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`t3`, tables=[], type=DROP]
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSnapshotChangeEventSource.createSchemaChangeEventsForTables(MySqlSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:539)
    at io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.doExecute(RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:127)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:70)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Schema-Registry Exception error logs:

```
    io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.RestUnknownLeaderException: Leader not known.
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.Errors.unknownLeaderException(Errors.java:153)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.register(SubjectVersionsResource.java:286)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:159)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.serviceImpl(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:502)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.UnknownLeaderException: Register schema request failed since leader is unknown
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.registerOrForward(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:594)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.register(SubjectVersionsResource.java:266)
    ... 60 more
```

Can someone help me what this exception means and how to resolve it?

Comment: Having exactly the same error, did you solve it? Do you have multiple schema registry instance in your cluster ?

Comment: Yes i solved it by deleting all the schemas related to the connector in schema registry and restarting the schema registry pod. I have only one schema registry server.